# Progress Bar stopping when tab is not in focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, blogger

I'm using the following code for a progress bar:

```html
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
  <!--progress-bar-->
</div>
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
var width = 1;

function progressBar() {
  resetProgressBar();

  id = setInterval(frame, 300);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width +"%";
    }
  }
}
function resetProgressBar() {
  width = 1;
  elem.style.width = width;
}
progressBar()
</script>
<style>
.slide-progress-bar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color:rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.36);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ff4546;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
}
</style>
```

It works fine (when the page loads, progress bar starts and completes 300frames) but when I switch the tab or minimizes the window it stops and when I reopen the tab, it resumes. I don't want this top happen. I want the progress bar to continue loading even when not in focus. Is there way to do so ?, cause I saw such progress bars on may other sites.

Comment: try using css3 transitions instead of js animations.

Comment: well, i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Interval stops when page is minimize. You can use Date object to check how many time pass since progress bar starts loading.

```html
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
  <!--progress-bar-->
</div>
<script>
var animationTimeInMiliseconds = 30000; //30s 
var interval = 300;
var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
var beginningDate = new Date().getTime(); // Time in miliseconds

function progressBar() {
  resetProgressBar();

  id = setInterval(frame, interval);

  function frame() {
  var milisecondsFromBegin = new Date().getTime() - beginningDate;
  var width = Math.floor(milisecondsFromBegin / animationTimeInMiliseconds * 100);
  elem.style.width = width + "%";

    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }
}
function resetProgressBar() {

  elem.style.width = 0;
}
progressBar()
</script>
<style>
.slide-progress-bar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color:rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.36);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ff4546;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this's the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 transitions instead of js animations to solve the problems you are facing.
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)
Adding an example for your reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
 .slide-progress-bar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color:rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.36);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-progress-bar .progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ff4546;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
  animation: progres 4s infinite linear;
} 

@keyframes progres{
    0%{
      width: 0%;
    }
    25%{
        width: 50%;
    }
    50%{
        width: 75%;
    }
    75%{
        width: 85%;
    }
    100%{
        width: 100%;
    }
};
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```